# Write to a text file in my project's assets folder Windows Phone 8.1

Tags: c#, file-io, windows-phone, windows-phone-8.1

I have tried to write to a text file in my project's assets folder. The program runs without error but I couldn't see any content in the text file. Can anyone please help me?

```
StorageFolder asset_folder = await Package.Current.InstalledLocation.GetFolderAsync("Assets");
StorageFile asset_file = await asset_folder.CreateFileAsync("TextFile1.txt", CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);
using(Stream s_Asset = await asset_file.OpenStreamForWriteAsync())
{
    await s_Asset.WriteAsync(data, 0, data.Length);
}
```

The *Build Action* is also set to *Content*.

Let me know if I have gone wrong somewhere...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't modify a package content from the application. So to write to a file you have to copy the file from the assets folder to the application's IsolatedStorage.

[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/ff402541(v=vs.105).aspx)

Comment: Will I be able to update the file in assets folder once I finished modifying the content in applications's IsolatedStorage?

Answer (score 0):

You can't write to *Package.Current.InstalledLocation* - it's read-only. If you want to add there something, you have to do it during production.

If you want to write some files in your app - use [ApplicationData.LocalFolder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.storage.applicationdata.localfolder.aspx).

Some more help you will also find [here at MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh758319.aspx).